# Fake go environment from a shell script

Tags: intellij-idea, goland

I am using ultimate with goland plugin and `dep`. I used to work outside `GOPATH` as well. Usually without idea I am using a shell script and `Makefile` to build project and was so far happy with it. Idea with `dep` integration of course forces me to work inside `GOPATH/src`. Is there any way to configure that IDE to run a shell script which will fake project environment, set `GOPATH`, `GOBIN` and make `dep` happy and get rid of `... is not within a known GOPATH/src` and "missing" imports.

I have tried to run it via `./build/env.sh idea .` but still getting missing imports and `... is not within a known GOPATH/src`. Tried to play with project settings as well, seems nothing can satisfy that `gep`.

env.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [ ! -f "build/env.sh" ]; then
    echo "$0 must be run from the root of the repository."
    exit 2
fi

project="proj"
repositoryRoot="domain.com/username"

# Create fake Go workspace if it doesn't exist yet.
workspace="$PWD/build/_workspace"
root="$PWD"
dir="$workspace/src/$repositoryRoot"
if [ ! -L "$dir/$project" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    cd "$dir"
    ln -s ../../../../../. $project
    cd "$root"
fi

# Set up the environment to use the workspace.
# Also add Godeps workspace so we build using canned dependencies.
GOPATH="$workspace"
GOBIN="$PWD/build/bin"

# Run the command inside the workspace.
cd "$dir/$project"
PWD="$dir/$project"

# Launch the arguments with the configured environment.
exec "$@"
```

Makefile

```
.PHONY: all test clean

GOBIN = build/bin

all:
    build/env.sh go get github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep
    build/env.sh $(GOBIN)/dep ensure
    build/env.sh go build -v -o $(GOBIN)/proj
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, you cannot. GoLand/IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate with the Go plugin cannot work in the desired way. They respect the Go Workspace layout, and you should structure your code as such.

If you switch from `dep` to Go Modules, then you'll be able to create your project anywhere and not have the same restrictions as the GOPATH mode has. Here you can read more about [working with Go Modules](https://blog.jetbrains.com/go/2019/01/22/working-with-go-modules/).

Comment: "They respect the Go Workspace layout" they can respect whatever they want, the idiocy of ignoring ENV in a shell from where users call `idea .` is just dumb.

Comment: It's likely not ignoring what's in the ENV configuration, just that it's ignoring the symlinks for that due to a number of reasons. Of course, it would be better to open an issue on our tracker and see the logs, but as I said, in the case of symlinks, that won't solve anything. Why are you not using the Go Modules support instead?

Comment: I did, hard to struggle with that mess.